# Creating Advanced Search with text & Dropdowns

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, search

I am working to develop an advanced search option. Where there will be fields:

1. Text input Field (Post Title)
2. Dropdown (it will be a taxonomy)
3. Dropdown (it will be a taxonomy)

Basically I need this kind of search option. Please take a look at the image to better understand.

I am using the solution found [here](http://fearlessflyer.com/2012/10/how-to-create-an-advanced-search-form-for-wordpress/) for searching taxonomies but I need to integrate the text field which will get data from Post Title field..

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) Please post your code.

Comment: Is there any custom-fields involved?

Comment: I've tried a solution here http://fearlessflyer.com/2012/10/how-to-create-an-advanced-search-form-for-wordpress/
Everything works great. But what I need is to integrate another text field. The field will search data from post title

Comment: You can see what I did here : http://demo.mamb2b.us/directory/
Haven't worked for deseign yet... Just working for fields & functionalities..